# Implicit conversion loses intger precision xcode 5.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, warnings, xcode5.1

since xCode 5.1 I get to following warning:

```
Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') to 'SInt32' (aka 'int')
```

at the following line:

```
(void) CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToCFHost(NULL, host, port, &readStream,&writeStream);
```

marked ist 'port'

this is the declaration:

```
+ (void)getStreamsToHostNamed:(NSString *)hostName port:(NSInteger)port inputStream:(NSInputStream **)inputStream outputStream:(NSOutputStream **)outputStream
```

Can anybody help me with this warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the third parameter of `CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToCFHost` is of type `SInt32`, all you need is to change the signature of your `getStreamsToHostNamed` method as follows:

```
+ (void)getStreamsToHostNamed:(NSString *)hostName
                         port:(SInt32)port
                  inputStream:(NSInputStream **)inputStream
                 outputStream:(NSOutputStream **)outputStream
```

In general, you should avoid implicit conversions between NS wrappers of integer types, because these have platform-dependent implementations. Fortunately, compiler issues warnings about this, so you don't have to track them down manually.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, if I cande this i get the warning in the getStreamsToHostNamed method:"Conflicting parameter typs in implementation of'get....Stream:':'NSInteger' (aka 'long') vs 'SInt32' (aka 'int') any idea?

Comment: @Nils Did you change the type in both the .h header and the .m implementation files?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I see is to change the NSInteger to SInt32 or change the SInt32 to NSInteger, depending on how big the numbers need to be.  If you are only going to be using between -2147483648 and 2147483647, then SInt32 should be good enough.  If that is the case and there is no way of changing either one, just use an explicit cast to SInt32 to bypass the warning, though it could affect the results if the number is out of that range.

Comment: thanks for you replay I Think the range of SInt32 in enough. But how can I do a explicit cast to SInt32?

Comment: I think the other answer is more likely what you need, then.  I agree with changing the NSInteger to SInt32 in your GetStreamsToHostNamed method.

Comment: But if you really are set on casting it, you should do the following:

`CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToCFHost(NULL, host, (SInt32)port, &readStream,&writeStream);`